# How to Merging multiple domains into a single website?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am implemented one web application in ASP.NET(C#), for this web Application login Webpage implemented in some other Server in HTML, how can i merge both applications. first Login html page will come here he will check user credential on my server system after login is successful it redirect to my web application,here my application is in different place and different server how can i do it..

Comment: a) Why do you do that?
b) Have the login page write a cookie, and read that cookie in your ASP.NET page to authenticate the user.

Comment: Login html page has Domain registers, so after checks usercredentials it redirected to my web application..here user details are stored in my sever system.